# IgnorePointer partially, not the entire widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to make the touch go through on specific part of the widget so that the widget below handles the gesture. IgnorePointer does that on the entire widget. Is it possible to do it partially?

In iOS, there's UIView.point(inside:with:)

Answer (score 1):

I created my own widget.
hitTest method can decide whether to allow the touch. If you want specific widgets to allow points, use GlobalKey object to use for the touchable widget's key and use that global key to get the context and the render object. With render object and set type as RenderBox. Use the extension I wrote and call rectFromAncestor to get the rect and call contains to check whether to point is inside the widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class RenderIgnorePosition extends RenderProxyBox {
  /// Creates a render object that is invisible to custom hit testing.
  RenderIgnorePosition({
    RenderBox child,
    @required bool Function(BoxHitTestResult, {Offset position}) hitTest,
  })  : _hitTest = hitTest,
        super(child);

  final bool Function(BoxHitTestResult, {Offset position}) _hitTest;

  @override
  bool hitTest(BoxHitTestResult result, {Offset position}) {
    return _hitTest(result, position: position) &&
        super.hitTest(result, position: position);
  }
}

class IgnorePosition extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  /// Creates a widget that is invisible to hit testing.
  const IgnorePosition({
    Key key,
    @required this.hitTest,
    @required Widget child,
  })  : assert(hitTest != null),
        super(key: key, child: child);

  final bool Function(BoxHitTestResult, {Offset position}) hitTest;

  @override
  RenderIgnorePosition createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return RenderIgnorePosition(
      hitTest: hitTest,
    );
  }
}

extension RenderBoxExtension on RenderBox {
  Rect rectFromAncestor(RenderObject ancestor) {
    final offset = localToGlobal(Offset.zero, ancestor: ancestor);
    return RRect.fromLTWH(
      offset.dx,
      offset.dy,
      size.width,
      size.height,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would the following Widget arrangement work for your purpose?

```
Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
        Container(/* Whatever is not covered by Positioned Widget below will be handled here */), 
        Positioned(
           top: //Place it over the area where you to ignore, 
           child: IgnorePointer(
                  child: SizedBox(
                             height: //desiredHeight,
                             width: //desiredWidth)
]);
```

Comment: I tested this in an OverlayEntry() and it did not work...